# fatal: write error: No space left on device MiB | 127 KiB/s fatal: index-pack failed

Tags: update

I have 8GB Kingston Memory card but when i am trying to Update my RPi it gives this error after 80% loading,

```
sudo rpi-update
```

[image]

I don't know what is happening , I have done this update before on the same SD card and it went alright. But this time it is not working.
I have written the OS Image like 3 times to solve the problem, also tried 4 different SD Cards but the issue stays.

Comment: Just because you are using an 8 GB card does not mean that you have an 8 GB root filesystem -- unless you  resize one, the partitions (there are two of them) in the raspbian image are < 2GB total.  **Post the output from the `df` command.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you go into raspi-config and increase the partition size?  The image is of a 2GB partition.  If you want the partition to fill the whole card, you need to open a terminal and type `sudo raspi-config` then select the option to increase the file system size.  Once you've done that you should be able to update your Pi without filling the partition.